# Where (how) can I print exported Cards (or books) from iPhoto

Tags: photos.app, printing

I designed a holiday greeting card in iPhoto (which is great) but I wanted to see if there was a cheaper option for printing. I'm able to export the card as a PDF by CTRL + right-clicking on the background

[image]

I tried to then upload my PDF to fedex-kinkos to see if they would do the printing but they said its a non-standard size and I couldn't make much progress.

Has anybody had experience with a 3rd party printer using iPhoto designed cards or books?

Thnks!!

Comment: It would appear your issue isn't with the format, but merely the sizing. Find out what sizes they can use & make it to that.

Comment: My question is if anybody can ready and easily just take the standard output format